# HIVE: How does 'LIMIT' on 'SELECT * from' work under-the-hood?

Tags: hadoop, memory, hive, limit

Just wondering how does limit work for the following simple query

```
select * from T limit 100
```

*Imagine table T has 13 million records*

Will the above query:
1. first load all 13 million into memory & display only 100 records in the result set ?
2. Loads only 100 & gives the result set of 100 records

Was searching for it for quite some time now, most of the pages only talk about using the "LIMIT" but not how Hive deals with it under the hood.

Any useful response appreciated.

Comment: **(1)** Run a thought experiment and validate your suggestions (remember  that we are dealing with a distributed system) **(2)** Suggest a technical test that will indicate the actual algorithm.

Comment: What does it matter?  It's psuedo-random at best, unless you include an order by clause, at which point you know the answer.

Comment: "2. Loads only 100" ... How would it load them? From where? What if you have 1000 machines, with only 1 record in each machine? All machines are going to run the same `SELECT * LIMIT 100` query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If no optimizer applied, hive end up scanning entire table. But Hive optimizes
>   this with **hive.fetch.task.conversion** released as part of [HIVE-2925](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2925), To
>   ease simple queries with simple conditions and not to run MR/Tez at
>   all.
>
> Supported values are none, minimal and more.
>
> **none**:  Disable hive.fetch.task.conversion (value added in Hive 0.14.0 with HIVE-8389)
>
> **minimal**:  SELECT *, FILTER on partition columns (WHERE and HAVING clauses), **LIMIT only**
>
> **more**:  SELECT, FILTER, LIMIT only (including TABLESAMPLE, virtual columns)
>
> Your question is more likely what happens when minimal or more is set.
>   It just scans through the added files and read rows until reach
>   leastRows() For more refer [gitCode](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/release-1.2.1/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/FetchTask.java#L127), [Config](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#hive.fetch.task.conversion) and [here](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/release-1.2.1/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/optimizer/Optimizer.java#L175)

Comment: so you mean to say it loads only 100 into the memory ?

Comment: Yes, Check going on here https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/release-1.2.1/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/FetchTask.java#L146

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood a "SELECT" in a hive issues a FETCH task instead of spawing a mapreduce task. Think of it like a 
hadoop fs -get Point to be noted here is FETCH task works only on 
SELECT *  and if you were to select a column fetch might not work.

Source : https://vcfvct.wordpress.com/2016/02/18/make-hive-query-faster-with-fetch-task/